# A puzzle on kprobe mechanism in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, arm, kprobe

I have a puzzule on how kprobe works when I read the source code of linux kernel for work needs, according to the [kprobe.txt](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~boutcher/kprobes/kprobes.txt.html) in linux kernel:

> 1.1 How Does a Kprobe Work?
>
> When a kprobe is registered, Kprobes makes a copy of the probed
>   instruction and replaces the first byte(s) of the probed instruction
>   with a breakpoint instruction (e.g., int3 on i386 and x86_64).
>
> When a CPU hits the breakpoint instruction, a trap occurs, the CPU's
>   registers are saved, and control passes to Kprobes via the
>   notifier_call_chain mechanism.  Kprobes executes the "pre_handler"
>   associated with the kprobe, passing the handler the addresses of the
>   kprobe struct and the saved registers.
>
> Next, Kprobes single-steps its copy of the probed instruction. (It
>   would be simpler to single-step the actual instruction in place, but
>   then Kprobes would have to temporarily remove the breakpoint
>   instruction.  This would open a small time window when another CPU
>   could sail right past the probepoint.)
>
> After the instruction is single-stepped, Kprobes executes the
>   "post_handler," if any, that is associated with the kprobe. Execution
>   then continues with the instruction following the probepoint.

Three steps are given, but why the `single` and `post_handler` procedure are needed? I mean after substitution of the original instruction by a breakpoint instruction, the processor is trapped to execute the `pre-handler`, why not just copy back the orginal instruction with pc minus 1 in the `pre-handler` and restore the interrupt context?

Please give a hint.

See the diagram [here](https://static.lwn.net/images/ns/kernel/KProbeExecution.png) for clearity.

Comment: The documentation you quoted has an explanation. Carefully read the portion following: "It would be simpler to single-step the actual instruction…"

Comment: @duskwuff Eh, yes, there it is, that is embarrassing, thank you.